# Remove Active Record Error in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm upgrading an application from Rails 3.0 to 3.1 and found the following error showing up in my tests:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f928c0ee310>
```

I have the following snippet that moves errors :

```
after_validation do

  self.errors[:image_size].each do |message|
    self.errors.add(:image, message)
  end

  self.errors[:image_extension].each do |message|
    self.errors.add(:image, message)
  end

  self.errors.delete(:image_size)
  self.errors.delete(:image_extension)

end
```

I still need to be able to move all validations from `image_size` and `image_extension`, but I'm not sure how do this in Rails 3.1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only method that removes anything is [`clear`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-clear) and the removes everything so I think you have to:

- Pull all the error messages out (probably using `to_hash`).
- Clear all the errors with `self.errors.clear`.
- Put all the error messages back in the right/desired places using `self.errors.add`.

Answer (score 6):

You can directly modify the hash-like messages attribute of the errors object, that is you can do this:

```
self.errors.messages.delete(:image_size)
```

This is not exposed in the documentation, but looking at the actual code for `ActiveModel::Errors` we find an attr_reader defined for @messages:

```
attr_reader :messages
```

so it looks like that directly accessing it should be *acceptable use*